# How to resolve 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios' Error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, google-colaboratory

for the following code:

`from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow` 
I get

> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'

I saw in the other similar questions that there is no `termios` module in Windows.

If so, is there any substitute for this (I'm using jupyter notebook)

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a local runtime environment with Google Colab, a "remote" runtime or just a "normal" local jupyter notebook? I have never worked with Colab, but AFAIK `from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow` is only required for Google Colab instances, whereas "normal" Python scripts and also jupyter notebooks could use `import cv2; cv2.imshow()`. I guess, that `termios` is needed by Google Colab instances for internal tty I/O (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/termios) and thus, not required for local execution (which I assume, as you mention running on Windows)

Comment: @albert i'm running on a local jupyter notebook ,guess ill try with cv2 instead now